# Auto - Resize NatTable dynamically

Tags: nattable

I want to Auto - Resize NatTable dynamically according to the number of rows. 
In other words, I have a nattable of height 'x' with 10 rows. If rows are less than 10 then the height of nattable should reduce, so that empty space cannot be seen. If number of rows exceeds 10, vertical scroll bar should come.

Answer (score 1):

That is a SWT layout question in the end. Basically you are asking for a way to specify a minimum height based on the table content. You could solve this with a GridLayout and a resize listener that updates the minimum height dependent on the available container height.

```
Composite panel = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
NatTable natTable = new NatTable(panel);

// minimum height of NatTable + scrollbar
int minHeight = natTable.getPreferredHeight() + 18;

GridDataFactory
    .swtDefaults()
    .align(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING)
    .grab(true, true)
    .minSize(SWT.DEFAULT, minHeight)
    .applyTo(natTable);

panel.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        GridData data = ((GridData) natTable.getLayoutData());
        // minHeight + 10 because of the margins
        if (panel.getBounds().height < (minHeight + 10)) {
            data.minimumHeight = SWT.DEFAULT;
            data.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        } else {
            data.minimumHeight = minHeight;
            data.verticalAlignment = SWT.BEGINNING;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this is just one solution for this. There might be more elegant ones dependent on the layout you are using.